# Where to set attribute for virtual method parameter?

Tags: f#

I did not find a clear answer for this...

What is the F# equivalent of this C# code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual SomeMethod([Attribute] Int32 param)
    { }
}
```

Because there are two different places to put the attribute in F#:

```
type SomeClass () =

   abstract SomeMethod : [<Attribute>] param:Int32 -> Unit
   default this.SomeMethod ([<Attribute>] param) = ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it on both, but the override (`default`) is the one that counts.

```
type T =
  abstract M : (* [<Out>] this is okay too *) i: byref<int> -> unit
  default this.M([<Out>] i) = () //but this one's necessary
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! So if I add attribute `A` to abstract and then attribute `B` to default, is `A` 'overwritten'? Or does that just count for duplicate attributes?

Comment: It seems like the default is the one that counts. I was just pointing out that you can duplicate it on the abstract member, presumably for documentation purposes. It seems to be ignored.